# Looking for mapAccumLM

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a way to use mapAccumL in the IO monad - something like an analog of mapM, i.e. with this type signature:

`mapAccumLM :: (Monad m) => (a -> b -> m(a, c)) -> a -> [b] -> m(a, [c])`

Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically `mapM` on `StateT a IO`:

```
mapAccumLM f a xs = runStateT (mapM (StateT . f) xs) a
```

Answer (score 2):

In a very similar manner to `mapAccumL`:

```
mapAccumLM :: Monad m => (a -> b -> m(a, c)) -> a -> [b] -> m(a, [c])
mapAccumLM _ a [] = return (a, [])
mapAccumLM f a (x:xs) = do
  (a', c) <- f a x
  (a'', cs) <- mapAccumLM f a' xs
  return (a'', c:cs)
```